# Disabling IPv6 leads to black screen on reboot

Tags: ubuntu, networking, ipv6, pop-os, sysctl

I tried disabling IPv6 using **/etc/sysctl.conf** and after a reboot I cannot get into any of the two DE that I have installed (I am using *Pop! OS 20.04*). Tried both Pop Desktop and KDE Plasma. The SSDM login screen does show up but after successfully logging in I get a black screen and only the cursor is visible.

`Ctrl` + `ALt` + `F2` does work as intended and if I remove the lines that are supposed to disable IPv6 using *Vim* and reboot, everything seems to work normally.

This is what I added at the end of the file:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

My question is, how can I even begin to troubleshoot this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a file called e.g. `/usr/share/xsessions/safemode.desktop`

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=Safemode (Xterm)
Comment=
Exec=xterm
Terminal=False
TryExec=xterm

[Window Manager]
SessionManaged=true
```

Restart SDDM or reboot. Log into "Safemode (Xterm)". Now run:

`startplasma-x11` or `env GNOME_SHELL_SESSION_MODE=pop /usr/bin/gnome-session --systemd --session=pop` (all the entries are in `/usr/share/xsessions/` - check for `Exec` ).

Check for error messages in the terminal window. To finish this `xterm` session, simply type `exit` or `reboot`. If anything prevents you from using this xterm, type <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>